# How can I extract a zip file archive in dart asynchronously?

Tags: dart

I'm using the [archive](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/archive) package to expand a zip file like this:

```
  final bytes = new File(zippedFile).readAsBytesSync();
  final archive = new ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(bytes);

  for (var file in archive) {
    final filename = '/Users/mark/blah/${file.name}';
    if (file.isFile) {
      var outFile = new File(filename);
      outFile = await outFile.create(recursive: true);
      await outFile.writeAsBytes(file.content);
    } else {
      await new Directory(filename)
          .create(recursive: true);
    }
  }
```

Problem is that my UI thread in Flutter hangs from time to time which causes the CircularProgressIndicator to stutter - I suspect that the problem is the call to file.content.  How do call this without blocking on  the UI thread?  Do I need to use an isolate?

Comment: I'd consider using an isolate. You can use the `compute()` function from Flutter. It might depend on the size of the zip but if it stutters ...

Answer (score -1):

If using Flutter, here's one solution based on Günter Zöchbauer's comment:

```
  final bytes = new File(zippedFile).readAsBytesSync();
  final archive = new ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(bytes);

  for (var file in archive) {
    final filename = '/Users/mark/blah/${file.name}';
    if (file.isFile) {
      final decompressed = await compute(decompressArchiveFile, file);
      var outFile = new File(filename);
      outFile = await outFile.create(recursive: true);
      await outFile.writeAsBytes(decompressed);

    } else {
      await new Directory(filename)
          .create(recursive: true);
    }
  }
```

Here's the `decompressArchiveFile` function:

```
List<int> decompressArchiveFile(ArchiveFile file) {
  return file.content;
}
```

This works, but is about 5 times as slow as the [sync](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/archive#-example-tab-) approach.

Comment: You didn't use compute for anything serious.